# Is $A^3=A$ a condition for idempotency of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

> Given that $A$ and $B$ are two idempotent (square) matrices of same order, $AB+BA=AB-BA=O$ (Where $O$ is the null matrix of the same order). Prove that both $A+B$ and $A-B$ are idempotent.

I proceeded the following way:

> $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$.
>
> As $A$ and $B$ are idempotent, and $AB+BA=O$, $A^2+B^2=A+B$.

Thus, $A+B$ is idempotent, QED.

> Now, for the other part, (to prove $A-B$ is idempotent), I proceed like this:
>
> $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$.
>
> Again, as $A$ and $B$ are idempotent, and $AB-BA=O$, $(A+B)(A-B)=A-B$.
>
> Next, $(A-B)^3=(A-B)(A-B)^2$.
>
> $(A-B)^2=A^2-AB-BA+B^2=A+B-(AB+BA)=A+B$.
>
> Hence, $(A-B)^3=(A-B)(A+B)=A-B$.

Thus, I prove $(A-B)^3=A-B$.

Now, I have 2 questions:

1. Does this imply that $A-B$ is idempotent or not?
2. If not, how do I proceed further to prove it to be idempotent?

Comment: Pre-Multiplying by $(A-B)^{-1}$, we get $(A-B)^2 = I_n$. So yes its idempotent according to me.

Comment: @jeea How does proving (A-B)^2=I prove that (A-B) is idempotent? Doesn't that make it involutory?

Comment: Oh sorry I am so confused with these names!

Comment: @jeea: you can't assume $A - B$ is invertible here.

Comment: @RobArthan My prof. said that only $M=M^2$ is the sufficient condition... So does Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix

Comment: If you take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. You get that $A^2=A$, $B^2=B$, $AB=BA=0$, and $A-B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, which has $(A-B)^2=I\neq (A-B)$.

Comment: @jyre do you imply that the question isn't provable $\forall$ idempotent matrices (a wrong question)?

Comment: Let $A = [-1]$. Then $A^3 = A, A^2 \ne A$.